# Upgrading cordova 3.6.4 to 5.2.2 in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have an app in cordova 3.6.4 and I'm trying to upgrade it to 5.2.2. Everything seemed to work quite find with the UI however with the java files there is a problem.

I fixed some errors in the compilation time and the application now seems to open. However there are some errors that makes the app crash in run time.

Some of the errors are:

```
09-08 17:40:56.675 9729-9729/myapp E/chromium: [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2218)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing

09-08 17:43:17.535 9729-9729/myapp /chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()


09-08 17:43:34.185 9729-9821/myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 9821 (Chrome_InProcRe)
```

The application crashes when I start writing on an input element. I have tried to catch the event in chrome but without any success.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using any plugins? Parts of [this](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-cordova-5-readme/#changes-with-the-release-of-cordova-5) might be of interest anyway...

Comment: I'm using some customs and some already made, i.e.
battery-status,
camera,
contacts,
crosswalk-webview,
device,
dialogs,
echo,
email-composer,
file,
file-transfer,
geolocation,
globalization,
inappbrowser,
media,
network-information,
splashscreen,
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification,
vibration,
websocket. I think the problem is in mine but I'm not so sure how to trackdown the issue...any ideas might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have found in the code the reason why the app was crashing.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
```

This code gives the following error:

```
org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView
```

And the I had been using

```
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

which is giving as an error what I mentioned before.

It seems that with the crosswalk you can't change much if its settings.

And I was using it in the older version of cordova to overpass a ssl certificate error.